# How to download html file from another website

Tags: html

I want to download an html file from another website , I have tried the following code but it's not working , It just redirects to the website:

```
<a href='http://example.com' download>Download</a>
```

So how to download an html file from another website?

Comment: From where did you get the idea of adding a `download` attribute? your question is unclear, do you want to download the file using PHP? or using JS?

Comment: do you want to "download" it as a text in a variable or display it in your page ?

Comment: @MehdiBounya download is an attribute added to the `<a>` tag in html5. This should be used when href actually points to a file, not a directory.

Comment: Well that's a new thing for me. Thanks!

Comment: This question needs more explanation. In terms of tags, this has nothing to do with javascript, php, jquery or html.

Comment: I don't specify a specific programming language , Any of the tags (html , js , jq , php)

Comment: Visiting a site via browser will most likely try to render html rather than giving you the source as a download. Are you serving an html file as a download to users to your site? Are you wanting to do this one time for a specific site? Where are you trying to create a link for `<a href='http://example.com' download>Download</a>` and accessing it from? Using the tags you have means that the question is related to them. Because of your example, the only related tag is `html5`. Are you trying to scrape several html files? And if so, what code are you using and what have you tried?

Comment: @DanielGale , That's the only code I tried and it was working but now it is not , I know (PHP , HTML , Javascript , Jquery) , So I don't mind any of these solutions

Comment: @DanielGale , I want to download html files from the same website

Comment: so html5 download attribute is not going to work to download the html file so you need to write some serverside code that will fetch the url, and  return it so you can download it.

Comment: The first note from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) "This attribute only works for same-origin URLs."  If you are trying to do this for a URL that is not on the same site as this page, it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the comments, the download attribute only works for same origin URLs.

I solved this by exposing an endpoint in the backend that redirects to the url with the file I want to download, and pointing to that on the client side.

Frontend

```
<a href='/download-file' download>Download</a>
```

Backend

```
router.get('/download-file', (req, res, next) => {
  res.redirect('http://example.com/url-to-the-file');
});
```

Beware of what you are redirecting to if you don't have control over those files.

In my case the file was hosted in a CDN, which made the origin of the URL different, but I still had control over it.

Answer (score -2):

The `<a>` is for directing a user to a specified link. In html5 you may add the property `download` and link to a specific file to signify that you are intending to serve the file as a download.

In this case the href value should point to a specific file and not just a directory. The html file with the link must also be marked with a doctype for html5 at the top `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

You must serve the html/download from the same domain as your site or else deal with CORS which is another topic.

Example

```
<a href='http://example.com/myFileToDownload.html' download>Download Source</a>
```